# How To Use Magento Collections to Run Query, Get Results, and Print Them

Tags: magento, join, collections

I am fairly new to programming, php, Magento, and most of all, SQL. Please forgive me if this is somehow a dumb question.

I am trying to use Magento collections to select two different columns in two different tables  and join them. These two columns contain product numbers that follow the same conventions and my goal is to get and display the product numbers that field a (lets call it 'product_id') contains that field b ('item_nr') **does not**.

Here is my function so far, located currently in a model that will be called by a controller action.

```php
public function importCompare() {

    $orderlistCollect = Mage::getModel('personal_orderlist/orderlist')->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToSelect('product_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('b.item_nr', null)
        ->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft( array('b'=>$this->getTable('catalog/product')),   'main_table.product_id = b.item_nr', array('b.item_nr'));

    echo $orderlistCollect;
}
```

By echoing the variable, I get the following query.

```sql
SELECT `main_table`.`product_id`, `b`.`erp_item_nr`
        FROM `mag1personal_orderlist` AS `main_table`
        LEFT JOIN `` AS `b` ON main_table.product_id = b.item_nr
        WHERE (b.item_nr = '')
```

This looks fairly close to what I want, however the big problem is that **I have no idea how to retrieve the information I should derive from this query and echo it**. I've tried to use a variety of collection manipulation methods to no avail. Is it easy to use them out of order as well?

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Collections use interfaces from PHP's standard library to implement `for each`-able behaviors.

If that sounded like greek, give this a try.

```
foreach($orderlistCollect as $item)
{
    $data = $item->getData();
    var_dump($data);

    $sku = $item->getSku();
    var_dump($sku);

    $sku = $item->getData('sku');
    var_dump($sku);
}
```

If you're interested in learning how to do with with your own PHP objects, the [Object Iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) section of the manual is a good place to start.  However, there's no need to dive deep on this — just treat a collection like you would an array of objects, and you'll be fine.

Comment: thanks tons. My co-worker and I run around your website all the time.

I'm not actually trying to grab the skus. Is there anyway to getThisColumnName like you are using the methods getData() and getSku?

Comment: @ooblek6000 Each key in the data array can be turned into a setter or getter method.  The data key `sku` turns into getSku, the data key `this_column_name` would turn into getThisColumnName.